# Add colon after main tag in tag synonym page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, wording

I suggest a very little design improvement for tag synomym page: add a colon after main tag:

[Now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/synonyms):

> [image: discussion now]

Suggested:

> [image: discussion suggested]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colon has been added. That is all.

> one missing colon
> on the tab synonym page
> equilibrium